# Possible operations error, random single digit output

Tags: c++

I have written this program for a class that asks for a positive number and based on the number, calculations are performed. I had some great help from stack folks last week but was asked by my professor to re-write it and simplify my code. I have done that and now the math is not coming out right. I have run the debugger but I dont see where the values being passed are incorrect. Also, all numbers are failing the "if (number > 0)" test.

Could it be a compile error even though I get a successful build message?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>  
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    system ("color F0");

    int number, countIf = 0, countWhile = 0, countDo = -1, h = 0, i = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    char repeat = 'y';

    do {

        cout << "Please enter a positive integer or zero to quit: ";
        cin >> number;
        x = number, y = number;
        cin.ignore();

        if (number < 0) 
            cout << "Error: The integer entered was either not positive or a zero.\n" << endl;

        else if (number > 0)
        {
            if (number%2 == 0 && number%5 == 0)
                for (y%5; countIf <= y; countIf +=5)
                    {
                        i = y / 10;
                        i += countIf;
                        cout << countIf << " ";
                    }

            else if 
                (countWhile < x && number%2 == 0) 
                    {
                        countWhile += 2;
                        cout << countWhile << " ";
                    }

            else 
                {
                    countDo +=2;
                    cout << countDo << " ";
                }
        } 

            cout << "\n\nDo you wish to continue? (Y or N): ";
            cin >> repeat;
}
        while (number != 0 && repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');



    //cout << "\nThanks for playing!" << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;


}
```

Output should be similar to:

[image]

What I am getting is:

[image]

Comment: When you are simplifying code, you should test at every step. That way if it stops working, you'll know exactly where the trouble is.

Comment: It's not a compile error, it's a logic error. Try working through an example with pencil and paper. Incidentally, `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so `A && B || C` means `(A && B) || C`.

Comment: Your code is quite long. Make a copy, and start removing parts until you can no longer reproduce the problem, or until you get the "simplest possible" piece of code that still has a problem. In that latter case, you can come back and provide that code snippet, and I guarantee you it will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code like this:

```
        else if
            (countWhile < x && number%2 == 0)
                {
                    for(countWhile+=2; countWhile<x; countWhile+=2)
                        cout << countWhile << " ";
                }

        else
            {
                    for(countDo+=2; countDo<x; countDo+=2)
                        cout << countDo << " ";
            }
```

And I get output like:

```
Please enter a positive integer or zero to quit: 82
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80

Do you wish to continue? (Y or N): y
Please enter a positive integer or zero to quit: 75
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 61 63 65 67 69 71 73
```

Hope this helps.